# UIButton click causing app freeze/Rapid increase in memory

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

No error message, the button freezes in a "**pressed**" state and the app is unresponsive. In Xcode, I can see the memory rapidly increase in a continual manner.

The button press, ideally, should perform a segue to another screen.  Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

The problem lies in the `viewDidLoad()` function of the screen I am trying to segue to.  The lines of code have to do adding padding to the `textfields` in the `viewcontroller`.

```
let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, firstNameTF.frame.height))
firstNameTF.leftView = paddingView
firstNameTF.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

lastNameTF.leftView = paddingView
lastNameTF.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

userTitleTF.leftView = paddingView
userTitleTF.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Comment: Can you show your event handling code ?

Comment: Iits hard to say anything without seeing any of the code involved, but you're clearly stuck in some kind of infinite loop, probably in your view controller code.

Comment: There's no event handling code.  I drew a Push segue directly in the Xcode storyboard.

Comment: Okay the problem lies in a few lines in the viewDidLoad of the screen I am trying to segue to.  The lines of code are to add padding to the left side of a UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is you are trying to assign the same view to multiple left view...

Make changes like thi. I am not sure but it may help you....

```
let paddingView1 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, firstNameTF.frame.height))
firstNameTF.leftView = paddingView1
firstNameTF.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

let paddingView2 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, lastNameTF.frame.height))
lastNameTF.leftView = paddingView2
lastNameTF.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

let paddingView3 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, userTitleTF.frame.height))
userTitleTF.leftView = paddingView3
userTitleTF.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```